# lock code (can someone tell me how to improve)

Tags: python-3.4

hey I am very new to coding and I have created this relatively simple code to do with my basic knowledge of the language. However I have had to do with some unwanted code including shutting it down if password is too long. so could anybody help me with any improvements to this.

Thanks in advance,
Josh

```
import time


passwordx = float(input('create your password'))
def password():
    passwordx
    if passwordx>9999:
        print('password is wrong\n innitiating shutdown')
        x=5
        time.sleep(1)
        print(x)
        x-=1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(x)
        x-=1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(x)
        x-=1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(x)
        x-=1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(x)
        x-=1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(x)
        x-=1
        quit()



    else:
        print('code saved')
        x=1
        while x <1000:
            print('###############')
            x+=1

def login():
    passwordguess = float(input('please enter password'))

    if passwordguess == passwordx:
        print('access granted')

    else:
        print('wrong')
        print('here\'s a clue', (passwordx-passwordguess)**2)
        login()

password()
login()
```

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If not, please clarify the issue with a [mcve].

Comment: ok sorry didn't know will take this down sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A few general things:

1. Limit the validity of variables to the absolutely necessary.
2. Try to limit the dependencies of different variables to each other.
3. Avoid branches as far as possible.

[Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://file:///C:/Users/Gregor/Downloads/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf)

[PythonSpeed](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)

Comment: i'm sorry to bother you but I don't understand the terms you are using i'm only 14 years old and new too everything and barely know how it works. sorry

Comment: My preferred programming language is actually C #, but you can apply the same optimization in python.

Comment: ok i'm open to learning many languages but have only just started and I heard python was a good place to start. At first I was just copying youtube videos now I've been able to do stuff like above with just my knowledge and understanding but obviously it's not perfected.